# how to pass value from javascript to ASP control

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Good day,

Been new to web development (i use ASP.NET) and i had this goal of passing/returning a value to display on HTML element such such as input. I had done searching and trying most of the solutions i found but none work, the output still returns an empty value on the HTML input. why is that? my code i'm working on can be seen below:

javacript:

```
    function confirmExistence(entityValue) {
        var entity = "Staff";
        var result = "";

        if (entityValue === '0') {
            entity = "Student";
        }

        if (confirm(entity + " w/ same name is already registered. is this a different " + entity + "?")) {
            result = "Yes";
        } else {
            result = "No";
        }
        alert(result);

        document.getElementById('<%= fieldFirstNameStudent.ClientID %>').value = result;

    }
```

html:

```
<asp:button class="by-button" id="btnStudentEnc" runat="server" text="Encode" OnClick="btnStudentEnc_Click" />

<asp:textbox type="text" class="mfield" placeholder="First Name" id="fieldFirstNameStudent" runat="server" />
```

asp c#:

```
protected void btnStudentEnc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  **some sql database condition here to run the clientscript below**
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
                "studentConfirmExistence", "confirmExistence('0');", true); }
```

Result is as follows on this image:

[image]

UPDATE: IF ABOVE IS TOO COMPLICATED. i created a new web form having simple block of codes that still doesn't work

Aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="LobbyStudents.aspx.cs" Inherits="LobbyStudents" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content0" ContentPlaceHolderID="title" Runat="Server">
    LobbyStudents
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

    <script>
        function confirmExistence(entityValue) {
            alert(entityValue);
            document.getElementById("<%= fieldFirstNameStudent %>").value = "whatswrong?";
        }
    </script>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

   <asp:textbox placeholder="First Name" id="fieldFirstNameStudent" runat="server"/>
   <asp:button runat="server" text="Encode" OnClick="btnStudentEnc_Click"></asp:button>

</asp:Content>
```

Aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class LobbyStudents : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnStudentEnc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
         "studentConfirmExistence", "confirmExistence('0');", true);
    }
}
```

ClientScript works and even does the alert box. Still textbox is still empty and doesn't contain "whatswrong?" value

unlike i try it on this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="tch">

<p>Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="confirmExistence('0')">Try it</button>

<script>
    function confirmExistence(entityValue) {
        alert(entityValue);
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "whatswrong?";
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

where it works.

What's the difference between the two and why it doesn't happen on asp controls

Comment: I'd guess that you need an `onLoad` event listener. The last one works because your code is at the *end* of the body, thus it runs after everything has loaded. However, an ASP script manager will put it in the `<head>`, where it executes *before* everything has loaded.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) i tried that one also but then it doesn't work even showing it's alert dialog box doesn't work also unlike it was on header. putting the script under the elements inside the body of my contentplaceholder refering to the master page body doesn't work.

Comment: this might due to the position of the script, try to move the script below the html and run it again c it is working

Comment: Hi Se0ng11, what do you mean? your referring to the script on aspx right? you mean i should put my script outside my contentplaceholders?? i tried that one but it gives error and is that even possible to put something outside contentplaceholders?

Comment: move your script from head, to any position below your content2, any place below of it, as you using masterpage, at your master page, add a new placeholder, but below the content2, and then put ur script in that new place holder, or just move your script tag below your asp button will do, and try again

Comment: Hi Se0ng11, thanks for being attentive to help me :) i appreciate it alot. ok. here's what i did to the extent i understand what you mean, (1) i created a new placeholder id=aspjs at my master page below the existing placeholder id=content2. (2) i placed my script inside the new aspjs placeholder and this placeholder is under content2 placeholder. Is this what you mean? i tried this one but nothing happens even alert dialog inside script doesn't show up.

Comment: - i tried placing my script also inside the content2 placeholder and below the asp button, but still same, alert dialog doesn't show also. -have you tried this on your own and does it worked?

Comment: Stop trying to move your script around and just put it in an event listener. If your alert suddenly stopped working when you put it in an event listener, then you did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

ok, figure out what is the issue for your first example, is not related to the position, but

change your

```
document.getElementById("<%= fieldFirstNameStudent %>").value = "whatswrong?";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("<%= fieldFirstNameStudent.ClientID %>").value = "whatswrong?";
```

this will generated in html as

```
document.getElementById("System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox").value = "whatswrong?";
```

which the js not able to find the control name as **System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox**

if assign with .`ClientID`, it will generate the correct id

```
document.getElementById("MainContent_fieldFirstNameStudent").value = "whatswrong?";
```